# Class mapping using dart

Tags: oop, dart

I have this class(dart)

```
 class ResumenPublicaciones {
  String name;
  String count;

  ResumenPublicaciones({this.name, this.count});
  // named constructor
  ResumenPublicaciones.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : name = json['name'],
        count = json['count'].toString();
}
```

I want to map this response from the API

```
[{"name":"Administración","count":37},{"name":"Call Center,
Teletrabajo y Telemarketing","count":4},{"name":"Compras,
 Importaciones, Logística, Distribución","count":10}]
```

this is how Im doing it....

```
class ServicioResumenEmpleos {
  List<ResumenPublicaciones> publicaciones = [];

  List getResumenPublicacioness() {
    publicacionesResumidas();
    return publicaciones;
  }

  var apiUrl = "here my api URLs";

  Future<ResumenPublicaciones> publicacionesResumidas() async {
    var jsonResponse;
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };

    var response = await http.get(apiUrl, headers: headers);
    print('respuesta del api' + response.toString());
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(' el API responde ' + response.body);
      jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      var _listapublicaciones = new ResumenPublicaciones.fromJson(jsonResponse);
      publicaciones.add(_listapublicaciones);
      print(_listapublicaciones.name);
      return _listapublicaciones;
    } else {
      print(
          'Esta imprimiendo el else en este punto no  debe impremir el response');
      var _listapublicacionesNull = new ResumenPublicaciones();
      _listapublicacionesNull.count = '0';
      _listapublicacionesNull.name = 'didnt work';
      return _listapublicacionesNull;
    }
  }
//
}
```

*I want to receive a list on the class* but im receiving this error msg

Exception has occurred.

```
**_TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>')**
```

any Idea of what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```dart
var _listapublicaciones = new ResumenPublicaciones.fromJson(jsonResponse);
```

If your response is a list, you are passing it to a constructor that is expecting a `Map`. You need to iterate over the objects of your list and convert them into individual publicaciones:

```dart
var _listapublicaciones = (jsonResponse as List).map(
  (o) => ResumenPublicaciones.fromJson(o),
).toList();
```

Comment: Or:
`var _listapublicaciones = [for (var json in jsonResponse) ResumenPublicaciones.fromJson(json)];`

Comment: be sure to change your method to :   Future<List<ResumenPublicaciones>> publicacionesResumidas()